# How to expose a Qlist of enums from C++ to QML?

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qml, qqmllistproperty

I have a list of errors in c++ and I want to expose it to QML. Enum is registered using `Q_ENUM` and property is registered using `Q_PROPERTY`. You can see details below:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<LoginErrorCode> loginErrors READ getLoginErrors NOTIFY loginErrorsChanged)
    ...

public:
    ...
    enum LoginErrorCode {
        UsernameOrPassIsNotValid
    };
    Q_ENUM(LoginErrorCode)
    enum GetUserInfoErrorCode {
        GetUserInfoError_TokenIsNotValid
    };
    Q_ENUM(GetUserInfoErrorCode)

    QList<LoginErrorCode> getLoginErrors() const;
    ...
signals:
    ...
    void loginFailed();
    ...
    void loginErrorsChanged();
    ...
private:
    QList<LoginErrorCode> m_loginErrors;
};
```

and I registered `MyClass` using following line in `main.cpp`:

```
qmlRegisterType<MyClass>("ir.MyComponents", 1, 0, "MyClass");
```

and in QML I used that class using:

```
MyClass {
    id: myClass
    Component.onCompleted: login("irani", "iravani");
    onLoginFailed: console.log("Login failed with errors count: "+loginErrors.length);
}
```

and output is:

```
QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QList<LoginErrorCode>' for property 'MyClass::loginErrors'
qrc:/main.qml:46: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

**What is the problem?!

How can I expose my list of enums to qml?**
For `QQmlListProperty` documentation says:

> Note: QQmlListProperty can only be used for lists of QObject-derived
>   object pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [from the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html), `QList` is supported only for a limited set of types (`int`, `qreal`, and so on). See section *Sequence Type to JavaScript Array* for further details.
You should use `QVariantList` for your purposes instead. It is directly mapped to JavaScript `Array`. See section *QVariantList and QVariantMap to JavaScript Array and Object* for further details.
Note also the explicit mention:

> Other sequence types are not supported transparently, and instead an instance of any other sequence type will be passed between QML and C++ as an opaque QVariantList.

Of course, you can still use a `QList<LoginErrorCode>` internally, but a conversion to a `QVariantList` is required whenever you want to return it within the QML environment.

Comment: This works well, Thank you. As is suggested in the documentation, variant should be avoided when possible. So have you any other alternate way to expose list of enums to QML?

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi When possible. In your case, you can just go with a `QVariantList`. Otherwise you can use probably a `QList<int>` and easily convert back and forth your enum values. If you give it a chance, let me know if it works and I'll integrate the answer with this comment. ;-)